# I'm having a very difficult time making a nav-bar toggleable between hidden and unhidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

The issue I'm having is that I can create a simple toggleable menu switching display from none to blocks, but I'm struggling to understand how to use this method I found online, which would allow me to code the toggle menu but also have the menu pop in and out with a transition so it can look clean.

I've tried what I can, but with my lack of experience, and misunderstanding of the language is keeping me from getting what I wish, which is a horizontal menu that will slide in and out with a smooth transition. I'll be pasting my HTML, CSS, and JS.

```
<body>
    <header class="motto-header">
        <strong>
            WHEN YOU NEED A HAMMER TO SOLVE YOUR PROBLEMS
        </strong>
    </header>

    <section class="site-header">
        <div class="site-title">
            <a href="index.html">
                <h1>
                    <strong>
                        David J. Broderick LLC
                    </strong>
                </h1>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-toggle">
            <button h1 class="btn-nav">
                Navigation
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="navigationSect" id="navbuttoning">
        <a href="Services.html" >
            <button class="nav-btn" id="navbuttoning">
                Services
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="about.html">
            <button class="nav-btn"id="navbuttoning">
                About
            </button>
        </a>
 
        <a href="contact.html">
            <button class="nav-btn"id="navbuttoning">
                Contact
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="info.html">
            <button class="nav-btn"id="navbuttoning">
                Information Center
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <section class="banner">
```

This is the relevant section in HTML.

```css
.nav-toggle{
   text-align:center;
   height:4px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: table;

}

.btn-nav{
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ECC596;
    align-items:center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:center;
    border-radius:25px;
    z-index:15;

}

.navigationSect{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;

    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity:100%;
    z-index:-10;
    height:0px;

    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: transform ease-out .3s;
    transition: height ease-out .3s;

    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:0;

}

.navigationSect.is-open{
    transform:(translateY(0));
    height:100px;
}



.nav-btn{
    z-index:0;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:100%;
    width:25vw;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    background:none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;   
    transition: background-image 1s;        
    background-image:linear-gradient(#26373E,#26373e);
}

.nav-btn:hover{
    background-image:linear-gradient(#26373e,#ECC596);

}
```

and the JS code here is mostly copy/paste from here https://codepen.io/phebert/pen/yLybwWY

```js
const drawerTransitioner = transitionHiddenElement({
  element: document.querySelector('.navigationSect'),
  visibleClass: 'is-open'
});
  
document.querySelector('.btn-nav').addEventListener('click', () => {
  drawerTransitioner.show()
});
  
document.querySelector('.btn-nav').addEventListener('click', () => {
  drawerTransitioner.hide()
});
  
/** 
 * Library code
 * Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cloudfour/transition-hidden-element
 */
  
function transitionHiddenElement({
  element,
  visibleClass,
  waitMode = 'transitionend',
  timeoutDuration,
  hideMode = 'hidden',
  displayValue = 'block'
}) {
  if (waitMode === 'timeout' && typeof timeoutDuration !== 'number') {
    console.error(`
      When calling transitionHiddenElement with waitMode set to timeout,
      you must pass in a number for timeoutDuration.
    `);
  
    return;
  }
  
  // Don't wait for exit transitions if a user prefers reduced motion.
  // Ideally transitions will be disabled in CSS, which means we should not wait
  // before adding `hidden`.
  if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)').matches) {
    waitMode = 'immediate';
  }
  
  /**
   * An event listener to add `hidden` after our animations complete.
   * This listener will remove itself after completing.
   */
  const listener = e => {
    // Confirm `transitionend` was called on  our `element` and didn't bubble
    // up from a child element.
    if (e.target === element) {
      applyHiddenAttributes();
 
      element.removeEventListener('transitionend', listener);
    }
  };
  
  const applyHiddenAttributes = () => {
    if(hideMode === 'display') {
      element.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      element.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
  }

  const removeHiddenAttributes = () => {
    if(hideMode === 'display') {
      element.style.display = displayValue;
    } else {
      element.removeAttribute('hidden');
    }
  }

  return {
    /**
     * Show the element
     */
    show() {
      /**
       * This listener shouldn't be here but if someone spams the toggle
       * over and over really fast it can incorrectly stick around.
       * We remove it just to be safe.
       */
      element.removeEventListener('transitionend', listener);
  
      /**
       * Similarly, we'll clear the timeout in case it's still hanging around.
       */
      if (this.timeout) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      }
  
      removeHiddenAttributes();
  
      /**
       * Force a browser re-paint so the browser will realize the
       * element is no longer `hidden` and allow transitions.
       */
      const reflow = element.offsetHeight;
 
      element.classList.add(visibleClass);
    },
  
    /**
     * Hide the element
     */
    hide() {
      if (waitMode === 'transitionend') {
        element.addEventListener('transitionend', listener);
      } else if (waitMode === 'timeout') {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          applyHiddenAttributes();
        }, timeoutDuration);
      } else {
        applyHiddenAttributes();
      }
  
      // Add this class to trigger our animation
      element.classList.remove(visibleClass);
    },
  
    /**
     * Toggle the element's visibility
     */
    toggle() {
      if (this.isHidden()) {
        this.show();
      } else {
        this.hide();
      }
    },
  
    /**
     * Tell whether the element is hidden or not.
     */
    isHidden() {
      /**
       * The hidden attribute does not require a value. Since an empty string is
       * falsy, but shows the presence of an attribute we compare to `null`
       */
      const hasHiddenAttribute = element.getAttribute('hidden') !== null;
 
      const isDisplayNone = element.style.display === 'none';
 
      const hasVisibleClass = [...element.classList].includes(visibleClass);
  
      return hasHiddenAttribute || isDisplayNone || !hasVisibleClass;
    },
  
    // A placeholder for our `timeout`
    timeout: null
  };
}
```

If anybody could provide any tips or other methods that would lead to the same goal, that would be helpful. I just want to understand what I'm doing wrong, and what to do to be better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, you can toggle the is-open class on click.

Also, you are reusing the same IDs. IDs are meant to be unique. I would get in the habit of either NOT using them unless you have to, or always making sure they are unique.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn-nav");
let sect = document.querySelector(".navigationSect");
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    sect.classList.toggle("is-open")
});
```

```css
.nav-toggle{
   text-align:center;
   height:4px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: table;

}

.btn-nav{
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ECC596;
    align-items:center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:center;
    border-radius:25px;
    z-index:15;

}

.navigationSect{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;

    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity:100%;
    z-index:-10;
    height:0px;

    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: transform ease-out .3s;
    transition: height ease-out .3s;

    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:0;

}

.navigationSect.is-open{
    transform:(translateY(0));
    height:100px;
}



.nav-btn{
    z-index:0;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:100%;
    width:25vw;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    background:none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;   
    transition: background-image 1s;        
    background-image:linear-gradient(#26373E,#26373e);
}

.nav-btn:hover{
    background-image:linear-gradient(#26373e,#ECC596);

}
```

```html
<header class="motto-header">
        <strong>
            WHEN YOU NEED A HAMMER TO SOLVE YOUR PROBLEMS
        </strong>
    </header>

    <section class="site-header">
        <div class="site-title">
            <a href="index.html">
                <h1>
                    <strong>
                        David J. Broderick LLC
                    </strong>
                </h1>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-toggle">
            <button h1 class="btn-nav">
                Navigation
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="navigationSect" id="navbuttoning">
        <a href="Services.html" >
            <button class="nav-btn" id="navbuttoning">
                Services
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="about.html">
            <button class="nav-btn"id="navbuttoning">
                About
            </button>
        </a>
 
        <a href="contact.html">
            <button class="nav-btn"id="navbuttoning">
                Contact
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="info.html">
            <button class="nav-btn"id="navbuttoning">
                Information Center
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This code swept mine away and made it so much easier to understand. 

I got it to work how I want it to now!

Comment: @JordanPina I'm glad that it worked. BTW, I didn't notice it until just now but you shouldn't have the button tag within an anchor tag.